# Trouble Understanding how a file gets read

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble understanding how this line of Haskell code works...

```
main = interact wordCount
    where wordCount input = (show ( length ( words input))) ++ "\n"
```

I don't really understand how its able to read my file if I don't directly state which file I want it to read from?

Ive tried reading over how interact function works and I get how it works a tad bit.

Answer (score 1):

The `interact` function reads from the "standard input" and writes to the "standard output".  By default, these are just the input and output of the terminal where you run the program (i.e., input from the keyboard and output to the screen).  However, it's possible to use files as standard input or standard output or both instead.  Generally, if you run the compiled program from the command line with:

```
$ ./MyProgram
```

then you get the default terminal-based standard input and output, while if you run the program like so:

```
$ ./MyProgram <some_input_file.txt >some_output_file.txt
```

then you get input and output from the indicated files.

This isn't a Haskell-specific feature.  The operating system arranges for standard input and output to point to files when you run a command line program in this way, whether it's a Haskell program or some other other executable.

Comment: Is 'interact' storing the "standard input" into 'wordCount' ?

Comment: @ABOL No. It's calling the `wordCount` function with the text from standard input as its argument. In other programming languages, consider the difference between `wordCount = standardInput;` and `wordCount(standardInput);`.